# Does iOS SpriteKit support GIF file?

Tags: ios, gif

I am working on iOS application which requires simple persona animation with Audio. I achieved that with SpriteKit and texture atlas and it works perfectly fine. The only issue is the size as i have around 500 images. Does SpriteKit support GIF animation where i can supply only one GIF file and it will animate. also i want to animate transparent image.

Comment: I would also like to know answer. As far as I can see, it doesn't.